# color-theme-install undefined

Tags: elisp, emacs23

I updated to GNU emacs 23.3.1, and my configuration file, which worked under GNU emacs 23.1.1, gives me an error that says `color-theme-install` is void. Is there any way that I can fix it?

Comment: Dear moderator. I would like this question to be closed. It turned out not to be a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with require in the file. It is solved now.

Comment: Select this as the correct answer to close out this question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have color-theme.el installed. Try the [installation instructions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme#toc1).